# Angular-Material : md-select in md-dialog not closing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, mddialog, md-select

I've created a simple directive that consists in a form with few md-input and one `md-select`.

I've used my directives in a few pages now and everything works fine, but now i would like to use it inside an `md-dialog` and it's not working as expected, i can't close the md-select-menu if i click outside of it, even if i focus an md-input.

So the only two ways for the user to close the menu is to either select an option or dismiss the dialog.

It's not that bad but i found this rather annoying.

Here is the content of the dialog :

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Modal" ng-cloak flex="75">
    <md-toolbar ng-class="md-primary">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2 translate>personModal.update</h2>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="img/ic_close_white.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <person-form person="person"></person-form>
</md-dialog>
```

And the directive content :

```
<form name="createPersonForm" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" class="bg-sec query-fields">
    <md-input-container flex class="full-width-input">
        <label translate>createPerson.form.firstname</label>
        <input name="firstname" ng-model="person.firstname" required md-asterisk/>
        <div ng-messages="createPersonForm.firstname.$error"
             ng-show="createPersonForm.firstname.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required" translate>
                createPersonForm.errors.firstnameMissing
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>

    <!--                      -->
    <!-- Other md-inputs here -->
    <!--                      -->

    <md-input-container flex class="consumption-filter full-width-input">
        <label translate>createPerson.form.contact</label>
        <md-select name="contact" ng-model="person.contactId" required>
            <md-option ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-value="{{contact.id}}">
                <span>{{contact.name}}</span>
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
        <div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>
        <div ng-messages="createPersonForm.contact.$error"
             ng-show="createPersonForm.contact.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required" translate>
                createPersonForm.errors.contactMissing
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-button class="md-raised bg-white" ng-click="createPerson()" ng-disabled="createPersonForm.$invalid" ng-hide="loading" ><span translate>createPersonForm.errors.createButton</span></md-button>
    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" class="md-accent" ng-show="loading"></md-progress-circular>
</form>
```

I'm using Angular 1.5 and Angular Material 1.0 .

I tried toying around with z-index, and upgrading angular/angular material, but it doesn't solve the problem.

I'm considering closing the menu programatically when the md-select looses focus, but i found that kinda ugly. And i don't know how do to do that yet.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you figure out a fix?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: Had to do a dirty fix manipulating z-index and onClickListener of the md-scroll-mask when opening and closing the md-select

Comment: @Holt in case you're interested i posted an answer with what i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested here is what i've done to fix my problem. I know it's not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me. If anyone has a better idea feel free to share with us !

HTML :

```
            <md-input-container flex>
                <label>Category</label>
                <md-select ng-model="selectedCategory" md-on-open="dirtyFix()">
                    <md-option ng-repeat="cat in categories" ng-value="{{cat}}" ng-selected="$first">{{cat.name}}
                    </md-option>
                </md-select>
            </md-input-container>
```

JS :

```
$scope.dirtyFix= function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        $(".md-scroll-mask").css("z-index", 899);
        $(".md-scroll-mask").click(function () {
            $(".md-select-menu-container").remove();
            $(".md-scroll-mask").css("z-index", -1);
        });
    }, 500);
}
```

CSS :

```
.md-select-menu-container {
    z-index: 900;
}
```

Had to set a timeout to let the modal render and then toy with z-index and clicklistener.

It's far from perfect but maybe it'll inspire you !

Answer (score 6):

Using the method proposed by Freego above throws an error for me on angular-material 1.1.5

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$viewValue' of undefined
```

I got this fixed in angular-material 1.1.5 by setting the z-index for `<md-backdrop />` alongside `.md-select-menu-container`.

```
.md-select-menu-container {
    z-index: 900;
}

md-backdrop.md-select-backdrop {
    z-index: 899;
}
```

Comment: good answer.. A simple css hack did it. I have mentioned your answer to the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48379779/873976

Comment: @SandeepSukhija Thank you :-)